# Using NSPredicate/NSCompoundPredicate with Where clause or Optional Return, CloudKit

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

Not sure if the subject line makes sense, I have an `NSCompoundPredicate` which is working great, it query's date within 24 hours, if record is "blocked", and also only returns records of my custom "type".

What I mean by custom type is the value can either be a 1, 2, or 3.  So i want my query to return those of types 2 and 3, which works.  However, for the fancy part when there is a 3, there also will be a string value under "User Names"  value in the cloud kit database.  Under type 2, the user name will be blank.

So i want to return all type 3's with a user name of "Smith" then also all type 2's with no user name at all.  I am having trouble getting both the type 2's and the 3's with a user name of smith, the way i have it it only returns users with name smith and doesn't return any type 2's.  Need a way to have the UserName predicate be optional?

Code:

```
let predName = NSPredicate(format: "UserName CONTAINS %@", "Smith")
let customTypes = [2, 3]
let time = 86400
let fromDateDay: Double = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - time)
let predDate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %f", fromDateDay)
let predBlocked = NSPredicate(format: "blocked != %d", 1)
pred = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [customTypes, predDate, predBlocked, predName])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `customTypes` is not a predicate, so your code as posted should crash. You need to construct a predicate that takes into account the difference between custom type 2 and 3.

```
NSPredicate(format: 
 "(customType = 2 && userName contains %@) || (customType = 3)", "Smith")
```

Comment: thank you will try, i missed writing my predicate when i pasted the code.              let customType = NSPredicate(format: "UserName IN %d", argumentArray: [customTypes])

Comment: This also seems wrong. Conflating user name and custom types. Just use the predicate I provided.

Comment: actually, just tried it, thought it worked by returned the error, "Not a predicate comparison"

Comment: i read that using cloud kit you can not use a compound and with an or predicate.